# how to use more Like this query score to function score in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-java-api

how to use "more Like this" query score to function score in Elasticsearch

```java
    static FunctionScore mltFunctionScore(String text, Double weight, List<String> fields) {
        return new FunctionScore.Builder()
                .filter(new Query.Builder()
                        .moreLikeThis(new MoreLikeThisQuery.Builder()
                            .fields(fields)
                            .like(new Like.Builder().text(text).build())
                            .build())
                        .build())
                .weight(weight)
                .build();
    }
```

Using a function score will only use the "more like this" query as a filter.

Can I get the same score as the one from the match query and use it as a function score?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to utilize the score from the MLT query in your function score, you should not use it as a filter.

If I understand your question correctly this query should handle your problem:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "more_like_this": {
          "fields": ["your_field_name"],
          "like": "Your text here",
          "min_term_freq": 1
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "weight": 2
        }
      ],
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

In Java it should be:

```
FunctionScore functionScore = new FunctionScore.Builder()
    .query(new Query.Builder()
        .moreLikeThis(new MoreLikeThisQuery.Builder()
            .fields(fields)
            .like(new Like.Builder().text(text).build())
            .build())
        .build())
    .addFunction(new WeightFunction.Builder().weight(weight).build())
    .boostMode(CombineFunction.MULTIPLY)
    .build();
```

if you faced with an error you need to modify codes, because i don't have chance to test codes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
It uses java api 8.8.2, but there is no function score query function.

Comment: I'm using other scores are also used. (boostMode replace, socreMode sum)